# Difference between search results from the deezer api and the web site

Tags: deezer

When performing a search using the Deezer API, the results obtained are the not the same as the ones obtained when performing the search from the Deezer web site.

Is there a way to obtain the same results as the web site using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search results are localized based on the current user's country (IP based).
If you query the website and the API from the same location, you'll get the same results.

You can override the country by passing a user token to the request to make sure you always get the same results.

Comment: Doesn't seem so. I perform the requests from the same IP address and the results are different.

http://api.deezer.com/search?q=gareth%20emery%20sanctuary returns 16 items.

http://www.deezer.com/search/gareth%20emery%20sanctuary returns 2 items

Comment: They both return the same items but on the Deezer website, they are grouped by "similar results". The button is a bit hidden on the right of the song title.

Comment: I see. What is the rule to regroup similar items? Same artist and track name containing the name of the original one?